# Big O Notation - Proofs of computing rules

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic, numerical-methods

Let be $f, g: X \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ x_{0}$ a Limit point of X. Then we define the Big O Notation as

$f = O(g) \ if \ \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right | < \infty$, and $f = o(g) \ if \ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right | = 0$

How i can show a), b), c) for $h_{1} = O(f)$, $h_{2} = O(g)$, $h_{3} = o(f)$

My Ideas so far:

a) $h_{1}+h_{2} = O(\left | f \right | + \left | g \right | )$ ?

- $O(\left | f \right | + \left | g \right | ) = \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{h_{1}+h_{2}}{f(x)+g(x)} \right | = \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{h_{1}}{f(x)+g(x)} + \frac{h_{2}}{f(x)+g(x)} \right | \leq \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}( \left | \frac{h_{1}}{f(x)+g(x)} \right | + \left | \frac{h_{2}}{f(x)+g(x)} \right |) < \infty \Rightarrow h_{1}+h_{2} \in O(\left | f \right | + \left | g \right | )$

b) $c*h_{1}+h_{3} = O( f )$ ?

- $c*h_{1}+h_{3} = \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{c*h_{1}+h_{3}}{f(x)} \right | \leq \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} ( \left | \frac{c*h_{1}}{f(x)} \right | + \left | \frac{h_{3}}{f(x)} \right | ) = \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} ( \left | \frac{c*h_{1}}{f(x)} \right | + 0 ) < \infty \Rightarrow c*h_{1}+h_{3} = O( f )$

c) $h_{2}*h_{3} = o(f*g)$ ?

- $h_{2}*h_{3} = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{h_{2}*h_{3}}{f(x)*g(x)} \right | = 0$ because $h_{3}=o(f)$ $\Rightarrow h_{2}*h_{3} = o(f*g)$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your star $*$ is convolution as in mathematics?  or multiplcation as in a computer language?

Comment: just multiplication, sorry!

Comment: Do not write things like $O(\left | f \right | + \left | g \right | ) = \limsup_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} \left | \frac{h_{1}+h_{2}}{f(x)+g(x)} \right |$.

Comment: Is $h_{1}+h_{2} \Leftrightarrow O(\left | f \right | + \left | g \right | )$ better?